# TFS 2015 eclipse plugin notification config

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tfs

Recently I've changed my version of the TFS eclipse plugin from 2010 to 2015. I've noticed among many changes that when I update my files from the server, it doesn't show me anymore which files have been downloaded and overwritten, despite there being some of them.

Previously this messages appeared in the dedicated console for the plugin, under the title

> Team Foundation Server Messages

I still have this console and that title shows at the top, but no messages come out when I update my files.

I've looked for the configuration to change which notification messages are shown in Window -> preferences -> TFS and in the very own settings menu of the plugin and found nothing.

Where can I find this kind of configuration for the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it under "source control" after some time, posting in case it helps anyone:

[image]

Just change from "Check out files in the background" to "Display progress while checking out".